# Using Feedme to import data from ExpressionEngine 2

Tags: plugin-feedme

Im trying to get started using the Feedme plugin to import data from EE. Im working with the json template provided here: https://sgroup.com.au/plugins/feedme/guides/migrating-from-expressionengine

Ive been able to import data but when I include a rich text field Im getting errors – eg.

```
IGS Updates Test: Unexpected token "punctuation" of value ":" ("end of print statement" expected) in "<p>On Thursday the 1st of December last, the Limerick Chapter of the Irish Georgian Society opened the Christmas season with a fundraising Christmas party. The event was held in The Georgian House, No. 2 Pery Square, in Limerick. This historic house was built between 1835 and 1838 by Pery Tontine Company, forming part of a terrace known collectively as the Tontine Building. It was the last Georgian terrace built in Limerick. The building was restored by Limerick Civic Trust, with the support of the Irish Georgian Society and opened in 1999. We were delighted to give our guests an opportunity to enjoy an evening in the magnificent first floor rooms of the house and we thank Limerick City and County Council for use the venue.</p>
```

Some of the entries are importing, but the majority are not. Any help / pointers appreciated...

Comment: Any chance there is some unexpected whitespace in that data tripping up FeedMe?  i.e. vertical tab, etc.

Comment: @kevin-horan
what did you do to fix the problem? I'm experiencing exactly the same issue. Could you share the XML file/template that fixed the issue?

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar error when I was doing an import; some entries made it and others didn't. It ended up I had an error in my JSON file so be sure to [lint it first](http://jsonlint.com).

Comment: Thanks - I got it working with XML - I think whitespace was the issue.